# javascript - how to get object name or associative array index name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON object like such:

```
var list = {'name1' : {'element1': 'value1'}, 'name2' : {'element1': 'value2'});
```

How do I extract all the nameX string values?

For example, suppose I want to output them concatenated in a string such as: "name1 name2"

Use of jQuery in any solution is fine. Please advise...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get the keys of an object, there is `Object.keys` in ES5, which returns an array:

```
Object.keys(list).join(" "); // "name1 name2"
```

If you want to filter the keys, you can use `.filter`:

```
Object.keys(list).filter(function(key) {
  return key.indexOf("name") === 0; // filter keys that start with "name"
}).join(" "); // "name1 name2"
```

Comment: One note, though--the `keys` method was introduced in 1.8.5+. If you need back-compatibility, you might prefer to use an alternative like the `_.keys` shim from underscore.js (@mVChr's answer offers another)

Answer (score 5):

```
var names = Object.keys(list);
```

Answer (score 4):

For older browsers that don't support `keys`:

```
var list_keys = []
for (var n in list) {
    list_keys.push(n)
}
var names = list_keys.join(' ');
```

Comment: You should include a hasOwnProperty test: `if (list.hasOwnProperty(n))`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said a jQuery-based solution would be fine, here's a way to do it with jQuery that doesn't require an ES5 shim:

```
var itemString = $.map(list, function(item, key) {
    return(key);
}).join(" ");
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/a2AMH/

`jQuery.map()` iterates over the properties of an object or the items of an array and builds a new array based on the custom function we pass to it.  We then just join the results of that array into a string.  You can read about `jQuery.map()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).